# Comment tracking for a site using Facebook Comments social plugin

Tags: facebook

I have a website that I run and on said website I use Facebook's Social Plugin: Comments.

People come to my website and sometimes they leave comments. What I am looking for is a way to see the 'latest' comments.

Ideally to push them back to my site so other users can see them, but mostly I just want to be able to see them so that I can respond.

The two places I have checked are...

1. The Social Plugin: Activity Feed
2. The Insights page for my app

When I check the Activity Feed it shows me 'activity' that happened long ago. In fact 3 months ago is the most recent thing it shows, so thats not helpful or correct

When I check my insights page, specifically in the comments section it will show comment count, but it will not show me what the comments are or where they are... So thats annoying.

Am I missing something?

Oh and because people always ask here are some urls for if you want to check stuff for yourself.

The site is  http://gameachievements.org ( if you throw that domain into http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/ you can see the dated activity )

And for some recent comments so show that there are indeed comments http://gameachievements.org/achievements/view/7457

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page has an FAQ section:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

which contains:

> How do I access the comments left on my site?

The comments for every URL can be accessed via the graph API. Simply go to: `https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids={YOUR_URL}`

For example, the comments on this URL can be accessed via: https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments.

Also there is a link from that page to this [blog post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/490).